# XNIO / Undertow - queue size for IO threads

Tags: java, undertow, xnio

Undertow web server (or XNIO TCP server) accepts requests in the IO threads. If IO thread blocks, requests are accumulated in the queue.

Is there a way to track size of these queues (e.g. JMX)? What would be a good approach to track it?